# Symfony 2 Form inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got an issue with form inheritance using symfony2 and doctrine2.
Here's is the thing :

I've got an entity `users` nothing special just few field with the name, email, etc...

```
Ferncoder\Devis\UserBundle\Entity\users:
  type: entity
  table: null
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      unsigned: true
      nullable: false
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    name:
      type: string
      length: '45'
      nullable: false
```

I've got an entity `craftsMans` this table has a relation OneToOne with the `users` entity.

```
Ferncoder\Devis\UserBundle\Entity\craftsMan:
  type: entity
  oneToOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: users
      joinColumn:
        name: user_id
        referencedColumnName: id
  table: null
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      unsigned: true
      nullable: false
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
```

I've generated 2 form class `usersType` and `craftsmanType`. To create my craftsMan I've done my form like this :

```
class craftsManType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user', new usersType())
            ->add('company', 'text')
            ->add('fieldOfActivities', 'text')
            ->add('legalForm', 'text')
            ->add('siret', 'text')
            ->add('website', 'text')
            ->add('description', 'textarea')
            ->add('services', 'textarea')
            ->add('employee', 'text')
            ->add('phone', 'text')
        ;
    }
```

My form look cool until I want to get the values of my fields. The problem is that my `'user'` field is return as an array and not as an entity. DId I missed something? How can I generate my users Object from the field `user`. I don't feel like creating the object mays setting all the attributs is the best way to do.

Maybe I'm wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: At the view level, each data type is rendered as simple string or array. At the model level you should be able to get the object after binding your form. At which level are you trying to get the values?

Comment: I want to do that in my controller after having validate my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the data_class options to return an object instead of an array.
The documentation below explains that when forms are embedded in another form(s), it is necessary to use data_class.

Documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-data-class

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
$form->getData()->getUser();
```

Comment: I've did that already, but `getUser()` return an array with all my user form fields, what I want is the entity. Seems like there is not other option that filling the entity from the array...

Comment: Have you bound the form?    
$form->bind($request);  
Do this before $form->getData()->getUser();